# Xcode 9 Refactoring Support for C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I've been all over the documentation for Xcode 9 and all I know for sure is that global rename is available for C++.  I read another statement about method extraction being available for all "supported languages," but that was vague since they didn't specially list which languages would get it like they did with global rename.  I'm in an area with bandwidth exhaustion, so it's not so easy for me to download betas, can anyone confirm what all refactoring is available for C++ with Xcode 9?  I'm really hoping they didn't leave us C++ guys out again in this category.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 9 supports a number of different refactoring actions for C++ projects, including things like "Extract Function", "Generate Missing Function Definitions", "Add Missing Switch Cases" and others. In general the list of "supported languages" includes C/Objective-C/C++/Objective-C++ and Swift of course.

Comment: This is good to hear.  I know us C++ dudes have been asking for refactoring abilities in Xcode for a very long time.  I resorted to getting AppCode, which is killer for refactoring, but it will be nice to get some of these welcomed features inside my IDE of choice.